# Misleading error with ObjectBinding and List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to setup a basic list in SwiftUI but I'm getting a compile time error that doesn't make much sense to me. Here's the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'

Here is my code:

```
final class MainViewModel: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<MainViewModel, Never>()

    var tasks = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List($mainViewModel.tasks) { task in
            Text(task.title!) //compile time error here
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is more than likely another one of SwiftUI's misleading errors, but I cannot seem to find what the actual issue is. Am I setting up the binding incorrectly? Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `Binding` into the `List`.

It needs data which conforms to `Identifiable`.

**You got two options here**:

Either you make `Task` conform to `Identifiable`, or you use `.identified(by:)`.

```swift
struct Task {
    let title: String
}

final class MainViewModel: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<MainViewModel, Never>()

    var tasks = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        // HERE
        List(mainViewModel.tasks.identified(by: \.title)) { task in
            Text(task.title) 
        }
    }
}
```